# unable to download youtube videos using uc browser

Tags: uc-browser

In uc browser I went to YouTube and chose a video, clicked that blue video icon, ticked save to sd card and chose watch offline. Then I checked downloads after some time download error is coming.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Just download error

Comment: To download youtube videos you can use third party apps like tubecast, mytube ...

Comment: error with all videos or with some off them ?? i faced this issue ones (only with some videos) and i think its because the privacy policy on the channel

Answer (score 1):

you may try UC Browser PC version.

its downloading function is more stable than phone.

also it can download videos from Facebook.

here's the link to the official website: http://pc.ucweb.com/?from=ghx0005

Comment: This question is about using UC browser in Windows Phone not Windows PC. You cannot use the PC version of UC browser on mobile phones as it is not a Universal app.